# Button click not working in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

Button click not working in selenium webdriver.

Tried both using class name and xpath.

Submit Order

```
//*[@id="main-content"]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/button[2]
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does the wrong button get clicked? Does selenium claim it clicks the button but nothing happens? Does selenium thrown an error stating it can't fine the button? Something else? Please [edit] your question to add additional details.

Comment: Button not getting clicked and there is no response.

Comment: Again, please [edit]  your question to include the additional information.

Comment: Test your locator thusly: `System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id="main-content"]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/button")).size();`  The upper/lowercase of my suggested line might be incorrect - going by memory.  If it prints zero, then it's not finding any buttons at all with that xpath.

Comment: System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id="main-content"]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/button")).size();                            I got response as 2.

Comment: @VishwanathAnandS : Provide the HTML code. so that we can give you optimistic solution.

Comment: You can try with `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="main-content"]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/button[1]").click();`

Answer (score 0):

You may try to click button with Action Class or JavaScript Executor:

**Action Class:**

```
Action action=new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(WebElement to Click).click().perform();
```

**JS Executor:**

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(WebElement to Click));
```

Answer (score 0):

[selenium web driver element click not working in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38719797/selenium-web-driver-element-click-not-working-in-windows-10)

There are many reasons why click might not work, some of them:

1. Element is not intractable.
2. Other element will receive the click.
3. For some driver implementations, a bug on some end cases.
4. Rare - no apparent reason.

First, try the obvious one (submit, not click)

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@type='submit']")).Submit();
```

If the above didn't work, continue here.

In order to bypass all the `Click()` logic, use JavaScript to perform a raw click.

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@type='submit']"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

As an extension method

```
public static void JavaScriptClick(this IWebElement element)
{
    // get the driver
    var driver = (IJavaScriptExecutor)((IWrapsDriver)element).WrappedDriver;

    // execute the click
    driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
}

// usage
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@type='submit']")).JavaScriptClick();
```

**Resources**

You can check Selenium Extensions (open source) for more samples
under folder: `/src/csharp/Gravity.Core/Gravity.Core/Extensions`

https://github.com/gravity-api/gravity-core

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gravity.Core

If you use C# you can install the package and use it's extensions directly.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gravity.Core/

```
Install-Package Gravity.Core
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in these two ways

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id="main-content"]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/button"));
action.moveToElement(element).click();
```

Or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="main-content"]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/button")).sendkeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with the HtmlUnit driver. The solution was to re-enable css as I have disabled it in the driver configuration.

Presume the z-index was not loaded from the css, meaning the button was not reachable and therefore not clickable.